# Custom sorting on multiple fields in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-directive

I have a requirement to sort the ng-repeat list based on two fields:

1> status : red, orange, green.

2> date: (older to present date)

the sorting should be such that all red, than all orange and last all green

below is my JSON:

```
{
    "data": [
      {"name": "John", "startDate": "14,Feb,2015", "status": "orange"},
      {"name": "John1", "startDate": "18,Feb,2015", "status": "red"},
      {"name": "John2", "startDate": "28,Feb,2015", "status": "red"},
      {"name": "John3", "startDate": "14,Feb,2015", "status": "red"},
      {"name": "John4", "startDate": "19,Feb,2015", "status": "orange"},
      {"name": "John5", "startDate": "15,Feb,2015", "status": "green"},
      {"name": "John6", "startDate": "21,Feb,2015", "status": "red"}
  ]
}
```

I want the above JSON to sorted like below:

```
{
    "data": [
      {"name": "John3", "startDate": "14,Feb,2015", "status": "red"},
      {"name": "John1", "startDate": "18,Feb,2015", "status": "red"},
      {"name": "John6", "startDate": "21,Feb,2015", "status": "red"},
      {"name": "John2", "startDate": "28,Feb,2015", "status": "red"},
      {"name": "John5", "startDate": "15,Feb,2015", "status": "green"},
      {"name": "John", "startDate": "14,Feb,2015", "status": "orange"},
      {"name": "John4", "startDate": "19,Feb,2015", "status": "orange"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: First you say that the sort order is R/O/G. In the list you sort it as R/G/O. In any case, <li ng-repeat="datum in data | orderBy:startDate"></li> will  sort it by date. Your best bet it to give color_id to colors (red=1, green=2 etc) and sort it by color_id.